# Replace Key name array inputs jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a strange question. We have buttons that have data attributes with an id in it. [v1, v2 and v3].

```
<table id="table-1" data-car-id="v1">
    <tr><td>Header1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Content1 <input type="text" name="car[v1][marked][12]" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Footer</td></tr>
</table>

<button id="copy-2" data-car-id="v2">Copy Table</button>
<table id="table-2">

</table>

<button id="copy-3" data-car-id="v3">Copy Table</button>
<table id="table-3">

</table>
```

A little piece of Javascript copies the body of the above table to closest next one. (That works).

```
$("button[id^='copy']").click(function() {
    var $carId = $(this).attr('data-car-id');
    alert($carId);
    var $prevTable = $(this).prev("table[id^='table-']").prop('innerHTML');
    var $nextTable = $(this).next("table").html($prevTable);
});
```

But now the tricky part, the input name of all inputs in that tbody should be replace. While the market should remain unchanged

car[v1][marked][12] => car[v2][marked][12]

How can I do that? Make it yourself easy and use the JSFiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/ra35z8ff/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After copying the HTML over to the next `table` element, select all the children `input` elements and iterate over them. Use the [`.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the previous `table` element's `data-car-id` attribute with the current `button` element's `data-car-id` attribute.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/u4bp7t1m/)

```
$("button[id^='copy']").on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-car-id'),
        previousId = $(this).prev('button').attr('data-car-id');
        html = $(this).prev("table[id^='table-']").prop('innerHTML');

    $(this).next("table").html(html).find('input').each(function () {
        this.name = this.name.replace(previousId, id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Josh thanks for your help. I've edited the answer as it was grabbing the id from the wrong element. Not table but the button carries the id